# ScheduledJob scriptblock failing

Tags: powershell

I'm writing a script involving scheduledjob cmdlets which opens files that users want at a specific time. I'm able to schedule a job to run a scriptblock which opens .bat and .mp3 but I couldn't use the scriptblock to open other extension file (.txt, .doc, .mp4, .ps1). It's like this:

These commands worked fine:

register-scheduledjob -name abc -trigger $abc -scriptblock {start "d:\folder\a.mp3"}

register-scheduledjob -name abc -trigger $abc -scriptblock {start "d:\folder\a.bat"}

But these commands failed:

register-scheduledjob -name abc -trigger $abc -scriptblock {start "d:\folder\b.txt"}

register-scheduledjob -name abc -trigger $abc -scriptblock {start "d:\folder\b.doc"}

register-scheduledjob -name abc -trigger $abc -scriptblock {start notepad}

In the scriptblock I have tried using invoke-item and invoke-command but none of those succeeded. I then checked task manager to file running process, it turned out that those files I have failed to open were running in the background with no windows opened

Why does it happen? Do you guys have any solution? Please help me. It took me very long time trying to fix that problem!  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the default security/run behavior from "run whether user is logged in or not" to "run only when user is logged in".  You can do this with the ScheduledTask commands.  Note that the `Register-ScheduledJob` creates a scheduled task in the `Task Schedulers\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs` folder.  You can make the change like so:

```
$principal = (Get-ScheduledTask abc \Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\).Principal
$principal.LogonType = 'Interactive'
Set-ScheduledTask abc \Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\ -Principal $principal
```

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: But I searched on Internet for ScheduledTask and found that just some version of Windows can utilize that. Am I Wrong? Do you have any solution for all versions to be able to run those commands?

Comment: You can always use schtasks.exe `schtasks /change /IT /TN "\Microsoft\Windows\PowerShell\ScheduledJobs\abc"`